# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain_openai'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, py-langchain

Following `LangChain` docs in my `Jupyter` notebook with the following code :

```
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser


prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template("Tell me a short joke about {topic}")
model = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo")
output_parser = StrOutputParser()

chain = prompt | model | output_parser
```

[Docs](https://python.langchain.com/docs/get_started/installation) say that `pip install langchain` installs all necessary modules, including `langchain-community` and `langchain-core`

However, I get this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain_openai'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following solution worked for me.
I referred to the `API` [docs](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/chat_models/langchain_openai.chat_models.base.ChatOpenAI.html#).

```
from langchain_community.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
openai = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo")
```

Answer (score 9):

In addition to Ari response, from LangChain version `0.0.10`, the `ChatOpenAI` from the `langchain-community` package has been **deprecated** and it will be soon removed from that same package (see: [Python API](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/chat_models/langchain_community.chat_models.openai.ChatOpenAI.html?highlight=chatopenai#)):

```py
[docs]@deprecated(
    since="0.0.10", 
    removal="0.2.0", 
    alternative_import="langchain_openai.ChatOpenAI"
)
class ChatOpenAI(BaseChatModel):
```

The correct usage of the class can be found in the `langchain-openai` package, which (*for some reasons...*) **does not come by default** when installing LangChain from PyPI. The package is the following: [OpenAI Integration](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/openai_api_reference.html).

You can directly install the package by running:

```bash
pip install langchain-openai
```

LangChain is continuously evolving so it is generally difficult to keep the pace of those changing. I suggest to always refer to the **official documentation** for understanding where to find classes and functions based on the specific version of LangChain installed.